# CodeIgniter 404 error on controller/method routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm facing a little problem right now with CodeIgniter...

I have the following file :

```
applications/controllers/home/entretiens.php
```

Which looks like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Entretiens extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
             $data['page'] = "entretiens";
             $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
             $data['prenom'] = $session_data['prenom'];
             $this->load->model("Entretiens_model");
             $data['entretiens'] = $this->Entretiens_model->getAllEntretiens($session_data['id']);
             $data['main_content'] = 'home/entretiens_view.php';
             $this->load->template('entretiens_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('home/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function ajouter()
    {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}

?>
```

If I go with my browser on : `myurl/entretiens` I get the right page (the index method of the controller "entretiens"), but if I go to `myurl/entretiens/ajouter` all I get is a 404 from CodeIgniter.

Here's my routes file :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home/index_controller";
$route['login'] = "home/login_controller";
$route['user'] = "home/user_controller";
$route['entretiens'] = "home/entretiens";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

And the `config.php` (well, the interesting parts) :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://dev.hinsolite.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

And my `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

(This problem is on all the controlers, and not only `entretiens`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the relevant line in your `routes.php` as follows:

```php
$route["entretiens(.*)"] = "home/entretiens$1";
```

This treats as wildcard, everything after `entretiens` will be passed to `home/entretiens`.

Comment: Worked great ! 
Thanks for the help !